# Let $P$ be a minimization primal problem $\min c^T x$. Does $P$ and its dual $P^*$ always have the same number of optimal solutions?

Tags: linear-programming

Let $P$ be a minimization primal problem $\min c^T x$ and let $P^*$ be its dual.

I've been wondering about the following:

Suppose $P$ has exactly $n$ optimal solutions.

I know that $P^*$ also has an optimal solution $\bar u$ with the same objective value by *Strong Duality*.

Does $P^*$ also has exactly $n$ optimal solutions then ?

I know about *Complementary Slackness*, but haven't yet come across an example where the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: In linear programming you have one optimal solution (intersection of two or more constraints). Or you have infinite number of optimal solutions, if the objective function lies on a constraint. Thus you cannot have n optimal solutions.

Comment: The optimal solution may not be unique !

Comment: This is what I wrote. You can have an infinite number of optimal solutions.